# How to implement method from Model to form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have in my models.py method of Model:

```
 class Book(model.models):
        ...
       def generate_tag(self):
          return f'{self.inspection.series_of_tags}-{str(self.tag_number).zfill(7)}'
```

I want to implement this method in my form when I push on update view it generate new tag:

```
class TagForm(core.ModelForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)

        if self.cleaned_data['tag_number']:
            instance = Book.generate_tag(self.instance)
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'tag_number',
        )

my views.py

class BookUpdateView(BookViewMixin, core.UpdateView):
    form_class = TagForm
    template_name = 'book.html'
```

I want that when I click update view -  my field 'tag number' will give method from model 'generate_tag' when I save my Form!What I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: You set `instance = Book.generate_tag(self.instance)`, so from that moment on `instance` is a *string*, not a `Book` object.

Comment: Exactly where do you want to store the `tag`? You do not share any fields of `Book` to store the tag.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're doing in your form at the moment would work for a class method, `Book.generate_tag(self.instance)`. That's calling a method on the `Book` class.

Your `save()` also won't work correctly because it may return a string, not a `Book` object;

```
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)

        if self.cleaned_data['tag_number']:
            instance = Book.generate_tag(self.instance)
            # Here instance is a string, because `generate_tag(self.instance)` returns a string.
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

You probably want to exclude the field from the form as it doesn't get a value initially. Then you can generate the value in the view.

```
class TagForm(core.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = (
            'tag_number',
        )
```

```
class BookUpdateView(BookViewMixin, core.UpdateView):
    form_class = TagForm
    template_name = 'book.html'

    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model and generate the tag."""
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        tag = self.object.generate_tag()
        # do something with your generated tag, like assign it to a field.
        self.object.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Likely it is something like `self.object.tag_name = self.object.generate_tag()`, since the `generate_tag()` only *returns* a string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah I suppose these things sometimes need pointing out.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem YES I have this mistake:

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. 'str' object has no attribute 'generate_tag'

Comment: @KenIst: yor form is supposed to return a `Book` object, you implemented `save()` in such way that it returns a `str` if `self.cleaned_data['tag_number']` is truthful.